# Odoo8: How to translate website content added by the user from backend

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-website

I have made a custom module for odoo 8 that adds a photogallery on the website. The user can then add images and descriptions from the backend that will be automatically displayed in the frontend.

Is there a way to translate texts efficiently in odoo that is added "dynamically" by the user such as image descriptions or product descriptions?
My idea is that the visitor can change language in the frontend and the correct translation should then be displayed next to the image.

Or do I need to have a description field in the backend for each language that I want support for?

*EDIT*: 
The gallery is implementedd like this at the moment

```
    <t t-foreach="photos" t-as="photo">
        <table style="width:90%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:60%;"> <span t-field="photo.image" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}' /> </td>
            <td style="width:40%; vertical-align:top;" >
                <font size="4" face="Comic Sans MS">
                <u><t t-esc="photo.name"/></u><br></br>  
                <t t-esc="photo.description" /> 
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </t>
```

Is there a way to translate the content of the photo.description field and not just only the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to make the description fields translatable in the backend. Just add `translate=True` to the field definitions. I don't know how you've added the gallery, but if it was done correctly, multi language support should work with users that are logged in! All other website users (without login) should see the website in default language.

Comment: The gallery is implemented like this:
    <t t-foreach="photos" t-as="photo">
   <table style="width:90%" align="center">
   <tr>
    <td style="width:60%;"> <span t-field="photo.image" t-field-options='{"widget": "image"}' /> </td>
    <td style="width:40%; vertical-align:top;" >
     <font size="4" face="Comic Sans MS">
     <u><t t-esc="photo.name"/></u><br></br>  
     <t t-esc="photo.description" /> 
     </font>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
        </t>
I can translate the names of the fields but is there a way to also translate the content of a field?

Comment: As i wrote, on your photo model, add `translate=True` on the field definition of fields you want to be able to translate.

Comment: An example for a translatable field in Odoo --> `product.template` name

Comment: Thank you for taking your time for answering and sorry for my messy answer.
I have added translate=True on the field-definition. But I still dont understand how I will be able to translate the content of the field. If I try to export the .po file I can only translate the field-names. And through the website-builder the texts are not translatable if i click edit-translations.

Comment: Ah, now i get what your problem is ;-) On edit mode (for example product) on the right upper corner on a translatable field there will be a little symbol (Odoo V7+8 a flag, Odoo V9 a globe) you can click. That will open the Translations.

Comment: Thank you very much I finally can translate the fields! :)